# IntelliJ IDEA git integration and staging area (index)

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Can the staging area (index) be used in a git based project in IntelliJ IDEA 12 or the concept is abstracted in the integration?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

UPDATE: This feature is available in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3+ versions.

---

Original answer:

Git index / staging area is not supported yet, feel free to [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63391).

Comment: It seems a lot of people have wanted this quite badly for a long time, and yet it still hasn't been implemented. Is this because 63 votes isn't that many, or is the project just lacking developers interested in doing it? (This isn't intended a criticism; I just think people might be more motivated if they knew what is causing the delay.)

Comment: @MichaelScheper you can never have enough developers =)

Comment: Given that companies live off tools such as SmartGit, I do not expect IntelliJ to support everything. Although I’d like to see everthing in one place, as well.

Comment: using git-cola to provide such functionality. It would be nice to see it in IntelliJ and in NetBeans too

Comment: Although there is no integration in the IDE, using the right-click menu `git > + add` does appear to have the desired effect (i.e. adding to the index rather than committing outright) ..

Comment: @Luciano I believe that git add in the context menu only works for the whole file, not a particular change, the selection, etc.

Comment: This is now supported with [IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#version-control)