# Commit index in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm

When using Git with IntelliJ IDEA, pressing Ctrl+K (for VCS Commit Changes...), it shows that what it's about to commit are all the changes, not just what's in the index.

I couldn't seem to find anywhere where it's possible to commit only the index so as of now I'm forced to use CLI's `git commit` command without `-a` to commit only the index.

By the way if you do a Stash within the IDE, it does give you a checkbox for whether you want to keep the index, so there is an example of the use of indexes in the IDE.

How can committing be done by only committing the index?

Comment: Not aware of it being available. I suspect they're attempting to simplify interactions with Git.

You can select which files to commit, but can't do partials. I rely on CLI or Sourcetree for more advanced interactions, but generally, if I don't want changes committed, I stash them first so I can do a local build and ensure I didn't miss something.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63391 (Not yet implemented)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA git integration and staging area (index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686010/intellij-idea-git-integration-and-staging-area-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available as of 2020.3 ([Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#use-git-staging-area-to-commit-changes), Issue: [IDEA-63391](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63391)).

Answer (score -1):

So, you got a set of files which are already tracked. Now, when you do `git status` these files are marked as ***modified***. At this stage these files are ***NOT*** staged. If you run `git commit -am "<commit message>"`, you will bypass staging and commit ***ALL*** files taht `git` system has knowledge of.

In order to keep index and stash everything else

```
git stash save --keep-index
```

The above will cause *staging area* **NOT** to be stashed. Then you can just run your usual `git commit -m "<commit msg>"`

Comment: Please re-read the question. The OP knows how to do this from the CLI. He wants to know how to do it within Intellij.